# Creating pseudodata based on actual data for code verification

Tags: r, replication

More and more academic journals require the submission of pseudodata upon the acceptance of an article for the purposes of verifying that the code used for the paper works (and assuming that the actual data cannot be published because of confidentiality/proprietary concerns).

For this purpose, I am looking for an R package/function that takes as input a dataframe and generates a fake dataframe with the same columns, column types, and number of observations as the original but completely artificial contents. I know of [packages](https://rviews.rstudio.com/2020/09/09/fake-data-with-r/) in R for the creation fake data but I haven't found one that does what I need.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Have you tried ChatGPT? Here is a question I have just asked: *"create fake data generation base R code such that the data.frame has 2 categorical variables, one with 2 levels and the other with 4, and a numeric column"*. The answer was correct.

Comment: This post has many solutions to create a dummy data: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example